# Symfony Forms - Is it possible to create a single entity from two forms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I understand that you can embed forms within another form. I wish to make 2 base forms for a User entity, with the following fields:

- UserCoreType: `username`, `password`, `email`
- UserPersonalType: `name`, `location`

With this I'd like to make a registration form, that included both of those types, and I'd like to make another form to only update the personal info (i.e. not really a new form, just use the UserPersonalType).

How can I do this without it trying to make 2 separate user entities, one for each form? I need one entity to be made.

OR

How can I restrict certain form fields? If I were to make just a single UserType, how could I make it so that only the name and location were editable after the entity had already been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just embed `UserPersonalType` into `UserCoreType` for registration form, and use `UserPersonalType` separately to update personal info.

**UPDATE**

You can also use single form for registration and updating info. Use `EventListener` on `PRE_SET_DATA` to make some of the fields readonly.

Comment: Okay, that seems like it would make sense. I'll give it a shot and see if I can make it work. Edit: Gave it a shot, and I think I'll just need to make a user's personal info a different database table for this solution to work.